# check pattern with DictReader in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a csv file like this :

```
    vahid,ajorloo,vahidlogin,ajorloo32@gmail.com,12345
    james,statham,jameslogin,jamesmail@gmail.com,1245844
    john,patinson,johnlogin,wrong-email-format,412541
    ali,mahdavi,alilogin,ali@gmail.com
```

i wrote this code :

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['first-name', 'last-name', 'login', 'email', 'password']

with open('list.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames)
    for i in csvreader:
     print(i)
```

the result is:

```
{'first-name': 'vahid', 'last-name': 'ajorloo', 'login': 'ajorloo32', 'email': 'ajorloo32@gmail.com', 'password': '12345'}
{'first-name': 'james', 'last-name': 'statham', 'login': 'jameslogin', 'email': 'jamesmail@gmail.com', 'password': '1245844'}
{'first-name': 'john', 'last-name': 'patinson', 'login': 'johnlogin', 'email': 'wrong-email-format', 'password': '412541'}
{'first-name': 'ali', 'last-name': 'mahdavi', 'login': 'alilogin', 'email': 'ali@gmail.com', 'password': None}
```

in the third line we have a wrong email format like mymail.com or my@mail without .com or any other wrong format.
in the last line the user didnt provide a password or maybe he just forgot that and leave it blank

i want to write a code that allows the program to tell me which input is missing and if the emails are wrong formatted show them so i can fix them.

im new to the programming world and this is the first program that im writing,i just need some guidance,is there any module for this kind of program that im building?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is missting or not using `if statement`.

In addition, you can check email validation using `regular expression`. (You can see how to use regular expression to find email pattern: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-python/)

Following code will print every missing value or invalid email as you want.

```
import csv
import re

email_pattern = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
fieldnames = ['first-name', 'last-name', 'login', 'email', 'password']

with open('list.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames)
    for i, item in enumerate(csvreader):
        if not item['first-name']:
            print(f'line {i+1}, No first-name')
        if not item['last-name']:
            print(f'line {i+1}, No last-name')
        if not item['login']:
            print(f'line {i+1}, No login')
        if not item['email']:
            print(f'line {i+1}, No email')
        if not re.search(email_pattern, item['email']):
            print(f'line {i+1}, Invalid Email: {item["email"]}')
        if not item['password']:
            print(f'line {i+1}, No password')
            
#line 3, Invalid Email: wrong-email-format
#line 4, No password
```